# crawl dynamic web page using htmlunit

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-crawler, htmlunit, infinite-scroll

I am crawling data using HtmlUnit from a dynamic webpage, which uses infinite scrolling to fetch data dynamically, just like facebook's newsfeed. I used the following sentence to simulate the scrolling down event:

```
webclient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webclient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
ScriptResult sr=myHtmlPage.executeJavaScript("window.scrollBy(0,600)");
webclient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
myHtmlPage=(HtmlPage)sr.getNewPage();
```

But it seems myHtmlPage stays the same with the previous one, i.e., new data is not appended in myHtmlPage, as a result I can only crawl the first few data on the web page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you found a way around ?

Comment: Looking for solutions too. Any results?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching the same thing. I was only able to find that it is not scroll event (90% sure). There is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423671/get-the-friends-of-my-friend-using-the-graph-api) on JS wich is responsilbe for loading the page and could maybe help you.

Answer (score -1):

I had similiar problem where the content were post-loaded during page scrolling. I solved it using:

`webClient.getCurrentWindow().setInnerHeight(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`