# How to Scrolldwon a web page using htmlunit or PanthomJS

Tags: java, html, dom, automation, htmlunit

I have a web page which **continues to loading** the contents when **ONLY** scrolling down the page.

So I want a way to scroll down the page pragmatically using HtmlUnit or PanthomJS.

1. Can I imitate the scroll down action(lets think using scroll element).
   or
2. Can i imitate it using j script.

if this can do please explain the way.

Thanks.

Comment: You can find some more informations in [this][1] question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119610/crawl-dynamic-web-page-using-htmlunit

Answer (score 2):

You can set InnerHeight a large value. like this:

```
webClient.getCurrentWindow().setInnerHeight(60000);
```

the  webcontrol will load all element,because of the webcontrol enough heigt.