# how to use httpclient 4.3.x grabbing infomation from web page with ajax

Tags: java, httpclient

for example，grab full content from https://play.google.com/store/apps

I found it posts data:

"start=15&num=5&numChildren=10pagTok=CA8QDxjh2ND3psHQ4pcB%3AS%3AANO1ljLBy5U&ipf=1&xhr=1"

to show next browser page
then I used

```
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://play.google.com/store/apps");
  List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start","15"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num","5"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numChildren","10"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pagTok","CA8QDxjh2ND3psHQ4pcB"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ipf","1"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xhr","1"));

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
    CloseableHttpResponse response = getSSLHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    try {
        if(entity != null) {
            return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
    } finally {
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        response.close();
    }
```

but in the end I can't get the web document from googleplay,the result is some javascript,
what's wrong？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache HTTP Client is used to get the page content. If you need to execute javascript on this page you can use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).
[Here](http://javabitch.blogspot.ru/2014/06/ajax-crawling-using-htmlunit.html) is an example

Comment: I used HtmlUnit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119610/crawl-dynamic-web-page-using-htmlunit ,didn't work for me

Comment: @RTM Some code would be nice. And btw check this out https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: thank you,I solved the problem by changing  param "start" and "num",I can get complete web content by posting "start=1&num=15&numChildren=10pagTok=CA8QDxjh2ND3psHQ4pcB%3AS%3AANO1ljLBy5U&ipf=1&xhr=1"