# how to get the list of friend's friend in c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-javascript-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graph API - get the Friends of my friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423671/graph-api-get-the-friends-of-my-friend)

how to get the list of friend's friend from Facebook in c# .net or in java script.
I am able to get the friend list with this method :--

```
string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me/friends");
```

but I have no idea how to fetch friend's friend. I am also getting the my friend's Facebook *id*.Is  there any way to fetch my friend's friend with his Facebook *id*?

Answer (score 1):

```
string myAccessToken = "something";         
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(myAccessToken);         

var friendListData = client.Get("/me/friends");
JObject friendListJson = JObject.Parse(friendListData); 

ArrayList<FbUser> fbUsers = New ArrayList<FbUser>();
foreach (var friend in friendListJson["data"].Children())             
{   
    FbUser fbUser = new FbUser();
    fbUser.Id = friend["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");                 
    fbUser.Name = friend["name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");                 
    fbUsers.add(fbUser);
}
```

Class for facebook user

```
Class FbUser {
    String Id { set; get; }
    String Name { set; get; }
}
```

[Facebook SDK C# - get friends list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584105/facebook-sdk-c-sharp-get-friends-list)

**EDIT:** You can't get friends of a friend:

[Get the Friends of my friend using the Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423671/graph-api-get-the-friends-of-my-friend)

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "Exception",
      "message": "(#604) Can't lookup all friends of <UID>. Can only lookup for the logged in user (<MY_UID>), or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate permission"
   }
}
```

Comment: it seems that this is the coding to fetch the friend list. I need to get the friend list of my face book friend. I need the list of my friend's friend.

Comment: you cant do that. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423671/graph-api-get-the-friends-of-my-friend.   Can only lookup for the logged in user

Comment: I tried. the link you provided gives two java functions. I tried those function but nothing is happeing. I just copied and pasted in the source of my asp page. please tell me the solution.

Comment: Read the previous comment. You cant get friend of friend facebook contacts. You can only lookup for the logged in user.

Comment: as I understand you mean I can not get the username and profile image of friends of my friend. m i right?

Comment: still looking for the response...

Comment: No dude, you can not access the friends of your friend information. Only current logged user information. Read the link I posted above

Comment: so in that case is there any alternate to get the username ,profile image of friends of my Facebook friend or at any cost it is not possible.

Comment: This is not a discussion chat. We cant be adding comments here. Accept the answer if you agree with it