# What calls are possible using an "app access token"?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm just starting to create a in-facebook app. I'm bugging at the first step, when a user access my app for the `first` time. Basically, I want a welcome page to explain what is that app before requesting an access to information. A cute image with cats, whatever, but not sending directly the user to the `login to my app dialog`.

So, user didn't sign in to my app, I only have the "app access token" to work with the graph. According to [this official Facebook dev page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/) (at the end), I'm supposed to have some basic information access.

Question is : **how ?** What are the calls that I can make to the graph with an `app access token` ?

`/me` is a no go, it requires a `user access token`.

`/$user_id` is public information, with or without a token, I can retrieve basic info. But I don't have any user_id to use through the `$signedRequest` (which gives only country,locale & age)

How am I to get (quote):

> ```
> - Basic Profile Info of a User (ID, Name, Username, Gender)
> - A User’s Friends and their IDs
> - Permissions granted by the User to your App
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using your application token for anything other than administration of your app.

It's not possible to get data before a user actually grants it.

The paragraph you mentioned is within the limits of your application

> While an App Access Token is largely for the purposes of publishing
>   information back to Facebook on behalf of the user, there is a limited
>   set of information that can be retrieved from Facebook using an App
>   Access Token.
>
> - Basic Profile Info of a User (ID, Name, Username, Gender)
> - A User’s Friends and their IDs
> - Permissions granted by the User to your App

Say I know User001 added my app, and I want to check on some items for administration. I don't have User001's access token (or rather I shouldn't be manually using it) So instead I supply the application access token to get data that would normally return

[image: Friends]

Notice I can supply an app token allowing me to see friends (of the user who added the app) but if I choose an object not mentioned in those bullet points...

[image: No access]

Comment: ok, thanks for the rapid comeback. I think i'm starting to understand things the "facebook" way.. Your first statement is what's important : APP access token is ONLY for administrative purposes, ONCE a user as already granted you access. Tell me if i'm correct on that, I belive the documentation should be more explicit on this usage. /me walk around looking for a different approach now

Comment: correct, /me is basically a shortcut for the current user/page that has been given an access token. If you have a user access token, me will return the authenticated user, if you have a page access token me will return the authenticated page.

Answer (score 0):

> - Basic Profile Info of a User (ID, Name, Username, Gender):

Yes. https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=id,name,%20username,%20gender&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

> - A User’s Friends and their IDs

If you request https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/friends?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN, you would get:

> {   "error": {
>       "message": "Can't lookup all friends of 100001234567. Can only lookup for the logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are
>   users of your app.", 
>       "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
>       "code": 604   } }

The answer for legal solution is, NO, you must use user access token.
Similar disscussion here [Get the Friends of my friend using the Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423671/get-the-friends-of-my-friend-using-the-graph-api)

```
Permissions granted by the User to your App
```

Yes. https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/permissions?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: But in the first place, I would need the USER_ID, which I can't retrieve without a specific grant access from the user. Along with that, token or not, you can get basic info from a user_id. The hard part is to first know with whom your app is talking to, which Facebook didn't make as easy as I would though... thanks for the comeback

Comment: Or you're able to access the user's cookies? The user id is inside cookies file, example:

 .facebook.com   TRUE    /       TRUE    0       c_user  12012345

Comment: i'm not a web developer, however, what i know is the cookie have the user id(If the user is loggedin). I'm not sure you able to retrieve the cookie or not, i just provide the possibility. :)